# monit status is failed but process works fine

Tags: monit

I am trying to deploy gunicorn using bosh release.It is randomly failing.some time it works fine other time it fails.

monit summary

```
Process 'gunicorn'                  Execution failed
Process 'nginx'                     running
Process 'consul'                    running
```

monit log is

```
[UTC Jul  9 11:56:06] error    : 'gunicorn' process is not running
[UTC Jul  9 11:56:06] info     : 'gunicorn' trying to restart
[UTC Jul  9 11:56:06] info     : 'gunicorn' start: /var/vcap/jobs/gunicorn/bin/monit_debugger
[UTC Jul  9 11:56:11] info     : start service 'consul' on user request
[UTC Jul  9 11:56:11] info     : monit daemon at 1383 awakened
[UTC Jul  9 11:56:11] info     : start service 'nginx' on user request
[UTC Jul  9 11:56:11] info     : monit daemon at 1383 awakened
[UTC Jul  9 11:56:11] info     : start service 'gunicorn' on user request
[UTC Jul  9 11:56:11] info     : monit daemon at 1383 awakened
[UTC Jul  9 11:56:36] error    : 'gunicorn' failed to start
[UTC Jul  9 11:56:36] info     : 'nginx' start: /var/vcap/jobs/nginx/bin/monit_debugger
[UTC Jul  9 11:56:37] info     : 'nginx' start action done
[UTC Jul  9 11:56:37] info     : 'consul' start: /var/vcap/jobs/consul/bin/monit_debugger
[UTC Jul  9 11:56:38] info     : 'consul' start action done
[UTC Jul  9 11:56:38] info     : Awakened by User defined signal 1
[UTC Jul  9 11:56:38] info     : 'gunicorn' start: /var/vcap/jobs/gunicorn/bin/monit_debugger
[UTC Jul  9 11:57:08] error    : 'gunicorn' failed to start
[UTC Jul  9 11:57:08] info     : 'gunicorn' start action done
[UTC Jul  9 11:57:18] error    : 'gunicorn' process is not running
[UTC Jul  9 11:57:18] info     : 'gunicorn' trying to restart
[UTC Jul  9 11:57:18] info     : 'gunicorn' start: /var/vcap/jobs/gunicorn/bin/monit_debugger
[UTC Jul  9 11:57:48] error    : 'gunicorn' failed to start
[UTC Jul  9 11:57:58] error    : 'gunicorn' process is not running
[UTC Jul  9 11:57:58] info     : 'gunicorn' trying to restart
[UTC Jul  9 11:57:58] info     : 'gunicorn' start: /var/vcap/jobs/gunicorn/bin/monit_debugger
[UTC Jul  9 11:58:28] error    : 'gunicorn' failed to start
[UTC Jul  9 11:58:38] error    : 'gunicorn' process is not running
[UTC Jul  9 11:58:38] info     : 'gunicorn' trying to restart
[UTC Jul  9 11:58:38] info     : 'gunicorn' start: /var/vcap/jobs/gunicorn/bin/monit_debugger
[UTC Jul  9 11:59:08] error    : 'gunicorn' failed to start
[UTC Jul  9 11:59:18] info     : 'gunicorn' process is running with pid 5670
```

process is also working fine
ps -ef

```
root      5670     1  0 11:59 ?        00:00:02 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 idmapi.wsgi:application
root      5682  5670  0 11:59 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 idmapi.wsgi:application
root      5685  5670  0 11:59 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 idmapi.wsgi:application
root      5686  5670  0 11:59 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 idmapi.wsgi:application
```

This  is happening randomly

When gunicorn succeeds i get following log

```
[UTC Jul  8 22:32:31] error    : 'gunicorn' process is not running
[UTC Jul  8 22:32:31] info     : 'gunicorn' trying to restart
[UTC Jul  8 22:32:31] info     : 'gunicorn' start: /var/vcap/jobs/gunicorn/bin/monit_debugger
[UTC Jul  8 22:32:36] info     : start service 'consul' on user request
[UTC Jul  8 22:32:36] info     : monit daemon at 1375 awakened
[UTC Jul  8 22:32:36] info     : start service 'nginx' on user request
[UTC Jul  8 22:32:36] info     : monit daemon at 1375 awakened
[UTC Jul  8 22:32:36] info     : start service 'gunicorn' on user request
[UTC Jul  8 22:32:36] info     : monit daemon at 1375 awakened
[UTC Jul  8 22:33:01] error    : 'gunicorn' failed to start
[UTC Jul  8 22:33:01] info     : 'nginx' start: /var/vcap/jobs/nginx/bin/monit_debugger
[UTC Jul  8 22:33:02] info     : 'nginx' start action done
[UTC Jul  8 22:33:02] info     : 'consul' start: /var/vcap/jobs/consul/bin/monit_debugger
[UTC Jul  8 22:33:03] info     : 'consul' start action done
[UTC Jul  8 22:33:03] info     : Awakened by User defined signal 1
[UTC Jul  8 22:33:03] info     : 'gunicorn' start: /var/vcap/jobs/gunicorn/bin/monit_debugger
[UTC Jul  8 22:33:33] error    : 'gunicorn' failed to start
[UTC Jul  8 22:33:33] info     : 'gunicorn' start action done
[UTC Jul  8 22:33:43] error    : 'gunicorn' process is not running
[UTC Jul  8 22:33:43] info     : 'gunicorn' trying to restart
[UTC Jul  8 22:33:43] info     : 'gunicorn' start: /var/vcap/jobs/gunicorn/bin/monit_debugger
[UTC Jul  8 22:34:13] error    : 'gunicorn' failed to start
[UTC Jul  8 22:34:23] error    : 'gunicorn' process is not running
[UTC Jul  8 22:34:23] info     : 'gunicorn' trying to restart
[UTC Jul  8 22:34:23] info     : 'gunicorn' start: /var/vcap/jobs/gunicorn/bin/monit_debugger
[UTC Jul  8 22:34:53] error    : 'gunicorn' failed to start
[UTC Jul  8 22:35:03] error    : 'gunicorn' process is not running
[UTC Jul  8 22:35:03] info     : 'gunicorn' trying to restart
[UTC Jul  8 22:35:03] info     : 'gunicorn' start: /var/vcap/jobs/gunicorn/bin/monit_debugger
[UTC Jul  8 22:35:33] error    : 'gunicorn' failed to start
[UTC Jul  8 22:35:43] error    : 'gunicorn' process is not running
[UTC Jul  8 22:35:43] info     : 'gunicorn' trying to restart
[UTC Jul  8 22:35:43] info     : 'gunicorn' start: /var/vcap/jobs/gunicorn/bin/monit_debugger
[UTC Jul  8 22:36:13] error    : 'gunicorn' failed to start
[UTC Jul  8 22:36:23] error    : 'gunicorn' process is not running
[UTC Jul  8 22:36:23] info     : 'gunicorn' trying to restart
[UTC Jul  8 22:36:23] info     : 'gunicorn' start: /var/vcap/jobs/gunicorn/bin/monit_debugger
[UTC Jul  8 22:36:25] info     : 'gunicorn' started
[UTC Jul  8 22:36:35] info     : 'gunicorn' process is running with pid 5780
```

**UPDATE**

```
    check process gunicorn
  with pidfile /var/vcap/sys/run/gunicorn/gunicorn.pid
  start program "/var/vcap/jobs/gunicorn/bin/monit_debugger gunicorn_ctl '/var/vcap/jobs/gunicorn/bin/gunicorn_ctl start'"
  stop program "/var/vcap/jobs/gunicorn/bin/monit_debugger gunicorn_ctl '/var/vcap/jobs/gunicorn/bin/gunicorn_ctl stop'"
  group vcap
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the bosh release you're using?  What's in the monit file that defines the `gunicorn` process?

Comment: I have created it mnaully .thi bosh release is no available online .I have Updated the question

Comment: You should check that when the process is running and monit says it failed that the process id in /var/vcap/sys/run/gunicorn/gunicorn.pid matches the id of the running process itself.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check if the `pid` of your process is there or not.
Generally it is stored in `/var/run/` folder.
If the `pid` file is missing you should manually kill & start the process.